# What's the deal with Music Meister?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, the-flash, supergirl

In *The Flash*, there is a musical episode that serves as a crossover with *Supergirl* and a way to further the romance of the characters of the Flash and Iris West. I thought that the Music Meister was quite a clever addition, as he seems to be symbolic of something. Possibly the writers, as he is this high-powered being that serves as a plot device that also makes the story into a musical. Seems kind of lazy, but interesting. But is there an in-universe reason for his high-poweredness? Has a writer or showrunner said anything?

Comment: he's "extra-dimensional", which in the DC universe usually means vastly over-powered. Similar to Mikhail Mxyzptlk (who also appeared on _Supergirl_)

Comment: FYI - to the best of my knowledge, Music Meister was originally created for the *Batman: the Brave and the Bold* cartoon a few years back, where he gave them an excuse to do the show as a musical episode. The basic idea may have been inspired by the *Buffy* season 6 episode *Once More, With Feeling* (though that may also have been inspired by something else. I think he's less about symbolism than just something fun to do with the show.

Comment: Anyone else getting the bit from Batman Beyond where they attend the Batman musical in their heads? A superstitious, cowardly loooooot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Music Meister is originally from *Batman Brave & the Bold*

The villain first appeared in the 2009 episode "[Mayhem of the Music Meister!](http://braveandbold.wikia.com/wiki/Mayhem_of_the_Music_Meister!)". In that incarnation, [Music Meister](http://braveandbold.wikia.com/wiki/Music_Meister) was an ordinary human who discovered that when he sang, he could hypnotize people to do their bidding.

> Bullies used to pick on me because I sang in choir /
>   but something very strange occurred as I kept singing higher /
>   the ruffians around me quickly fell into a trance
>   and it was then with wicked glee I made those puppets dance!

[image]

### Music Meister in the Arrowverse is an extra-dimensional being

[The Arrowverse version](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Music_Meister) of Music Meister is an extra-dimensional being. This is the second such being in the Arrowverse, with Supergirl having [Mxyzptlk](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Mxyzptlk) over on her show. We don't know a lot about where they come from, or if the two are related, but they appear to be all-powerful.

Unfortunately, I can't find any information about why the writers or showrunners decided to make Music Meister this way. Aside from the name and the general music motif, the version we see in the Arrowverse has little in common with the original version.

<sub>And I think it's a shame, because a villain who can force an entire town to do his bidding just by singing sounds way more appealing to me than what we got.</sub>

### "Star-Crossed" was an excuse to give actors who could sing a chance to do so

The episode [contained several *Glee* cast members](http://tvline.com/2017/01/23/darren-criss-the-flash-supergirl-music-meister-musical-episode/):

- Grant Gustin (The Flash)
- Melissa Benoist (Supergirl)
- Darren Criss (Music Meister)

And others who are talented Broadway singers:

- Jesse L. Martin (Joe West), starred in *Rent*
- Victor Garber (Dr. Martin Stein), member of [The Sugar Shoppe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sugar_Shoppe)
- John Barrowman (Malcolm Merlyn), [prolific singer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Barrowman#Discography)

If you ever wondered why Martin Stein and Malcolm Merlyn were in this episode, that's why.